# How to set up conversion tracking to optimize campaigns for approved user?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to finish my analytics setup and I've got a bit confused what is the best way forward. The end goal is to have tracking setup that enables me to optimize my Google and Facebook campaigns towards *approved users* instead of just *signed up users*. Our product has the following funnel:

1. User visits our website
2. He signs up for our product using website lead form (at this moment I have user's email, name, phone number etc.)
3. Based on our evaluation (that can take hours or days) the user is approved or disapproved in our CRM

I want to provide the advertising systems (mainly Google Ads and Facebook Ads) with an information when the user was approved with all the required ids so the system can trace the event back to the ad the user clicked.

I have the following analytical stack that I am working with:

- Website GTM container
- Server GTM container (GA4+ UA clients, GA4 + UA + FCAPI tags)
- Facebook Conversion API implemented in sGTM

What would be the best way in your opinion to implement the tracking of the event that is fired from our CRM when user is approved? I was thinking about using Measurement Protocol to send the event to sGTM/GA4 or Enhanced conversions for leads for Google Ads but neither solutions seems to fit 100 % to my scenario. What would you recommend? Thank you for any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

GA4 Measurement Protocol or Google Ads API and Facebook Ads APIs are the right way to go.

You'll have to store click & user identifiers ad platforms use (fbclid, fbp, gclid/_ga etc) and then pass them to Google Ads (either through GA4 measurement protocol and GA4-GAds connection or directly to Google Ads API) and Facebook CAPI together with the conversion. There are services like Able CDP that do the entire process - recording ids, getting conversions from CRM, sending them to APIs.

Doing it with sGTM or something like Zapier alone would be significantly limited. They don't remember what click ids, IP address, browser etc the user had when signing up and only around half of the conversions without click/user ids recorded at a lead form submission and sent together with the conversion will be attributed typically (the ones for which ad platforms recognise the users' emails).